# How to derive this formula with Gaussian integeration?

Tags: calculus, integration

Recently, I am reading *The Principles of Deep Learning Theory An Effective Theory Approach to Understanding Neural Networks* written by Daniel A. Roberts et.al. But I am stuck in the first chapter on a formula. It says:

> $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dz(e^{-\frac{z^2}{2K}})z^{2m}=(2K^2\frac{d}{dK})^m \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dze^{-\frac{z^2}{2K}}$

I don't know why the $(2K^2\frac{d}{dK})^m$ appears, maybe this is related to the formula:$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_{a}^{b}f(z,x)dz=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(z,x)dz$? But with $m$ times dirivatives, I can't calculate a simple term like $e^{-\frac{z^2}{2K}}$.

ps.The authers are with strong physics background, maybe it is a common trick in physics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}\newcommand{\D}{\mathfrak{D}}$I think $(2K^2\frac{\d}{\d K})^m$ should be interpreted as an $m$th iterate of the bracketed 'differential operator', *not* as: $$2^mK^{2m}\frac{\d^m}{\d K^m}\neq\left(2K^2\frac{\d}{\d K}\right)^m$$
I think the formula would be quite incorrect if one used the above left-hand-side. Let's call our operator $\D:=2K^2\frac{\d}{\d K}$. If we apply once: $$\begin{align}\D\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-z^2/2K}\d z&=(2K^2)\cdot\frac{\d}{\d K}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-z^2/2K}\d z\right)\\&=(2K^2)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2K^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty z^2e^{-z^2/2K}\d z\right)\\&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty z^2e^{-z^2/2K}\d z\end{align}$$

The only thing that has changed is the appearance of a new $z^2$ term. If we apply $\D$ a second time, we'd get $z^2z^2=z^4$ in the integrand. And so on.

So we see that: $$\D^m\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-z^2/2K}\d z=\int_{-\infty}^\infty z^{2m}e^{-z^2/2K}\d z$$Inductively. There is also nothing special about integrating from $-\infty\to\infty$ here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, and with your explanation, I can understand why this equality stands.

Comment: @UESTCfresh You’re welcome